# Group post by name from 2nd table php

Tags: php, mysql

This is litle complicated query for me, but if anyone have idea please post id...

I want to make something like this

**SITE 1** 
 post
 post
 post

**SITE 2**
 post
 post
 post

here is my query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT content.* FROM content WHERE content.site IN
          (SELECT site_id FROM site_subscription WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['userid'].")
          ORDER by content.site DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $array[] = $row;
}
```

AND im display post

```
if(is_array($array)) {  
    foreach($array as $row) {
        include($basepath.'/template/item.php');
    }
}
```

This is working and post is sorted by site_id, but need to get **site_name** from other table, table name **site** and than GROUP post by **site_name** like above **SITE 1, SITE 2, SITE 3**

Something like
`SELECT * FROM site WHERE id='content.site'`

Answer (score 0):

> "SELECT * FROM content INNER JOIN site ON content.site = site.id
>
> WHERE site.id IN (
>
> ```
>   SELECT site_id FROM site_subscription 
>
>           WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['userid'].")
> ```
>
> ORDER BY site.name"

Comment: And how to display site_name with this query above ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT content.* FROM content
                       INNER JOIN site ON content.site = site.id
                       WHERE content.site IN
                       (SELECT site_id FROM site_subscription WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['userid'].")
                       ORDER by content.site DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JOIN` instead of subquery. Try something like this:

```
SELECT content.*, site_name, FROM content 
JOIN site_subscription ON content.site = site_id
WHERE site_subscription.user_id = <USER_ID>
ORDER by content.site DESC
GROUP BY site_name
```

MysSQL will handle this query but it's not fully correct. You can't actually select `content.*` as you have to select only aggregated fields while you are grouping rows.

Comment: Have error with this query
`PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...`

Comment: This error occurs because you have `false` instead of resource returned by `mysql_query`. This means, the query is not correct. Check `mysql_error()" for details about SQL error. I gave you  just a template for the query that you're looking for. I don't know your exactly tables schema.